# how to update a contact in sql lite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application, I come up with a thing where I have to add a contact to the favorite list. I used this code to update the starred column of the contact table but all in vain. As far as I think, I am passing `null` to content values in my query, but I'm unable to figure out the possible correction.

```
try{
       ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 

       String[] projection={ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED};
       Cursor cur = cr.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,projection, null, null, null);

       cur.moveToPosition(Integer.parseInt(idholder)); //idholder holds unique row id
       cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,  null, Contacts.STARRED+"="+1, null);
}
catch(SQLiteException sqle){
       sqle.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns` you have a column called [`STARRED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactOptionsColumns.html#STARRED), which is boolean. So all you have to do is [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) the selected contact

Comment: could you please show me a code snippet.like if I have a row unique id  ,do I have to update each respective column in that row or just the starred column.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to give the answer. But if anyone finding the answer can use this.

```
private int updateContact(int val,String lookupKey) {
    // val = 0/1
    // you can also use _ID instead of lookupKey
    try {
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, val);
        return cr.update(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, values,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY+ " = ?",
                new String[] {lookupKey});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
    }
    return 0;
}
```